# Can I download a specific record by clicking on a custom button in the MUI X-Data-grid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mui-x-data-grid

I'm using MUI x-data-grid (community version) and want to download a record in CSV format by clicking on a custom button..
I know this can be achieved using the GridToolBar export option. But I want to trigger this on button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out MUI's documentation on CSV Export: https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/export/#customizing-the-rows-to-export

It has examples that match exactly what you need:

```
const CustomToolbar = (props: any) => {
  const apiRef = useGridApiContext();

  const handleExport = (options?: GridCsvExportOptions) =>
    apiRef.current.exportDataAsCsv(options);

  const buttonBaseProps: ButtonProps = {
    color: "primary",
    size: "small",
    startIcon: <FileDownloadIcon />,
  };

  return (
    <GridToolbarContainer>
      <Button {...buttonBaseProps} onClick={() => handleExport()}>
        Export As CSV
      </Button>
    </GridToolbarContainer>
  );
};
```

And you can pass in your desired export options into the handleExport function.